# 罫線で書かれたテーブルをhtmlに変換したいが…

Tags: html, アルゴリズム, テキストファイル

お世話になります。

プレーンテキストで書かれた、下記のようなテーブルを、htmlに変換したいと思っています。
特に言語は特定しませんが、正規表現の置換などを使用して、徐々にtableタグに落とし込んでいきたいと思っているのですが、流石に途中で頭が破裂しそうになりました。
じっくりやればできるような気もしますが、できれば良いアイデアをいただければと思います。

単純にpreタグで強引に表示するのはNGです。
やり方としては、『\n┌』を『\n＜table border="1"＞\n』に置換、『│』を『＜/td＞＜td＞』に
置換…などといった感じで加工していく方法です。

良い方法をご存知の方、アイデアをいただければ幸いです。

こんな感じのテーブルです。

```
┌───────────┬───┬───┐
│ＳＺＡ１２５　　　　　│価格│\1,500│
├─────┬─────┴───┴───┴──────────────────────────────┐
│出力名称　│名称　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
├─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│別名１　　│Ａとか　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
├─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│別名２　　│Ｂとか　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
├─┬───┴────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│追│　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
│加│　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
│内│　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
│容│　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│
├─┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││　　　　　メニュー　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
│├─────────────────────┬─┬───┬────────────────────┤│
││メイン　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│Ａ│　　１│パスタ　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　２│ラザニア　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　３│カレーライス　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
│├─────────────────────┼─┼───┼────────────────────┤│
││セット　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│Ｂ│　　１│サラダセット　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　２│コーヒーセット　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　３│食後のデザートセット　　　　　　　　　　││
│├─────────────────────┼─┼───┼────────────────────┤│
││大盛りサービス　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│Ｃ│　　１│ノーマル　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　２│ラージライス　　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　├───┼────────────────────┤│
││　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　│　│　　３│ハーフ＆ハーフ　　　　　　　　　　　　　││
│└─────────────────────┴─┴───┴────────────────────┘│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

完全にとはいかなくても、八割くらい近づけたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: colspan, rowspanで結合するにしても表の形がマッチしてないように思います。罫線文字列から変換するよりＨＴＭＬのＴＡＢＬＥ作成ツールで再設計する方が早いと思います。

Comment: 文字の2次元配列に、テキストを1文字ずつ入れていって、配列の中で表の構造を調べていく必要があると思います。具体的には、配列の中で、長方形の枠がどのように配置されているかを調べていきます。そして、長方形の集まりからtableの要素を再構成します。メニューの表が、外側の表の１つのセルの中に入っている構造であることを正規表現で検出するのは、たぶん無理だと思います。

Comment: 全角罫線は使えないと思いますが、ASCIIで書いた表形式をjsでテーブルに変換してくれるツールはあります https://casual-effects.com/markdeep/ テーブルのデモは https://casual-effects.com/markdeep/features.md.html#toc1.3

Comment: 皆さん、ありがとうございます。やはり完璧には無理ですよね。せめて、九割くらいは変換できれば、後は手作業でもいいかとは思うんですが。後、テーブルのマス目の数が合っていないのも、ある程度寛容にやってしまってもかまわないと思っています。

Comment: テキストをローカル環境で見てみましたが、`価格`と`パスタ`のセルがずれていました。それもうまい具合に補正されること期待していますか？ そもそもズレた`<table>`は表現不可能ですし…。

Comment: そこまでは期待していません。というよりは、テキスト上だとタブやフォントのタイプなんかで幅やサイズにずれができてしまうので、見た目通りというわけでなく、入れ子が正しくなっていれば良いかと。すみません、その所は本文に説明不足でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colspan`程度なら、以下のように割と簡単に変換できますが、`rowspan`と表のネストにまともに対応するのは手間が掛かりそうです。

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby; encoding: utf-8 -*-
class AATableParser
  def to_html(src)
    buf = []
    buf.push '<table border="1">'
    buf.push '<col width="32pt">'
    src.rstrip.split(/\r?\n/).each {|line|
      unless line.empty? or line.include?('─')
        buf.push parse_row(line)
      end
    }
    buf.push '</table>'
    buf.join("\n")
  end
  private
  def parse_row(line)
    buf = []
    buf.push '<tr>'
    is_first = true
    cur = 1
    line.split(//u).each {|c|
      case c
      when /│/
        idx = line.index('│', cur)
        if idx != nil
          colspan = idx + 1 - cur
          if colspan > 1
            td = %Q|<td colspan="#{colspan}">|
            buf.push is_first ? td : '</td>' + td
            is_first = false
          end
          cur = idx + 1
        end
      when /　/
      else
        buf.push c
      end
    }
    buf.push '</td>'
    buf.push '</tr>'
    buf.join('')
  end
end

def main
  src = ARGV[0]
  if File.exist?(src)
      parser = AATableParser.new
      buf    = parser.to_html(File.read(src))
      outf = open(src + '.html', "wb")
      outf.puts(buf)
      outf.close()
  else
    puts src
    puts 'No such file'
  end
end
main
```

```html
<table border="1">
<col width="32pt">
<tr><td colspan="12">ＳＺＡ１２５</td><td colspan="4">価格</td><td colspan="7">\1,500</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6">出力名称</td><td colspan="45">名称</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6">別名１</td><td colspan="45">Ａとか</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6">別名２</td><td colspan="45">Ｂとか</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">追</td><td colspan="49"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">加</td><td colspan="49"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">内</td><td colspan="49"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">容</td><td colspan="49"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="51">メニュー</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22">メイン</td><td colspan="2">Ａ</td><td colspan="4">１</td><td colspan="23">パスタ</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">２</td><td colspan="23">ラザニア</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">３</td><td colspan="23">カレーライス</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22">セット</td><td colspan="2">Ｂ</td><td colspan="4">１</td><td colspan="23">サラダセット</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">２</td><td colspan="23">コーヒーセット</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">３</td><td colspan="23">食後のデザートセット</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22">大盛りサービス</td><td colspan="2">Ｃ</td><td colspan="4">１</td><td colspan="23">ノーマル</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">２</td><td colspan="23">ラージライス</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="22"></td><td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="4">３</td><td colspan="23">ハーフ＆ハーフ</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
すべて完璧にとはいかなくとも、ある程度形になっていればいいと思います。早速試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

単純な置換では難しいです。

表の構造があらかじめ決まっている(行の区切りの回数を数えることでなんのデータが入っているか決定できる)場合は、上から1行ずつ読み込んで

- `|`を項目の区切り
- `適当な長さの`──`の連続を行の切り替わり

で判定して各セルのデータを拾っていき、最終的に改めてHTMLの表として再構築するのがよいでしょう。

表の構造が決まっていない場合(罫線で構成された任意の表をHTMLにしたい場合)、入れ子の表の判定であるとか、各項目の幅を判定してcolspanを適切に設定する、とか考える事が格段に増えるのでだいぶ面倒になります。サンプルデータのようにイレギュラーな幅のセルまで反映するとなると一筋縄ではいきません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり簡単には行きませんよね。『折る程度』までできれば、あとは手作業でもとは思うのですが、どのあたりまでカバーできるでしょうか。
ただ、あくまでも形式は不定なので、やはり罫線でパターンを見つけてやりくりするしかないのですが…。